# How can I uninstall Ubuntu from Windows 11

Tags: windows, 22.10

I was researching qbittorrent and saw a comment suggesting downloading Ubuntu. I don't know what it is or what it does (I had never even heard of Ubuntu), but I was trying to solve a problem in qbittorrent and thought Ubuntu would work.

So I downloaded Ubuntu 22.10 on my Windows 11 computer using bittorrent, and when it was done it had become a DVD disk in my computer. I can't uninstall it from my computer and I don't know what to do. Can i get some help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have downloaded the Ubuntu ISO and mounted it. You can simply right click on the mounted ISO (that is presented as a DVD disk) and eject/unmount it.